# What's the difference between == and : in swift extension where condition

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I have a question in swift extension:

```
protocol Racer {
    var speed: Double { get }
}
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Racer {
    func fastest() -> Iterator.Element? {
        return self.max(by: { (a: Iterator.Element, b: Iterator.Element) -> Bool in
            return a.speed < b.speed
        })
    }
}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Racer {
    func bla() -> Void {

    }
}
```

I am wondering what's the difference between them. In fact, an array of type `[Racer]` doesn't have `bla()` function.

---

Edit 1： There's still a question, assuming we have a struct conform to `Racer`

```
struct Human: Racer {
    var speed: Double
}
```

If we have an `Array<Racer>`:

```
let me = Human(speed: 99999)
let you = Human(speed: 99998)
let arr: [Racer] = [me, you]
// Threre's no problem, we can do this
arr.fastest()

// but 
let arr2: [Human] = [me, you]
// this Array won't have the `fastest` function
arr2.fastest() ------> Error!
```

So, I have to extension both `==` and `:` at the same time for the same function?

Answer (score 7):

When using `:` you are writing an extension for a type that conforms to a particular protocol or inherits a specified class.

When using `=` you are writing an extension for a specific type, in your case `Racer`.

You can read more in the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID553).

Edit:

One difference is that when you are using `=` the type must match, this means that the element type for the array **must** be `Racer`. 
This is why `Array[Human]` doesn't get the extension method, because the type isn't `Racer` is actually `Human`.

You don't need 2 methods, you can change the first one to use `:` instead of  `=`. Conforming to `Racer` protocol is enough, it doesn't need to be of `Racer` type.

Comment: Thx for that docs, I understood. Please see my edit, there's another question about it.

Comment: About the edit, I tried in playground and `[Racer]` won't have `bla()` func. For example,`[Human(), Dog()].bla()` won't work if I don't extension it using `=`